# No Player Exception. Cannot find a Player for: javax.media.rtp.RTPSocket@1eb0

Tags: java, exception, video-streaming, rtp, jmf

Good morning! I have these `VideoChatRTP` class I got [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/6.0-JDK-Modules/java-3d/com/db/media/rtp/VideoChatRTP.java.htm) (I just added the `main`) and an `EncodingUtilClass` class from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/6.0-JDK-Modules/java-3d/com/db/media/rtp/EncodingUtil.java.htm). 

VideoChatRTP.java

```
import javax.media.rtp.*;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import com.sun.media.ui.*;

/**
 * A RTP over UDP player which will receive RTP UDP packets and stream
 * them to the JMF RTP Player or (RTPSM) which is not aware of the
 * underlying network/transport protocol. This sample uses the
 * interfaces defined in javax.media.rtp.RTPSocket and its related classes.
 */
public class VideoChatRTP implements ControllerListener{

    /**
     * RTP Session address, multicast, unicast or broadcast address
     */
    String address = "";
    /**
     * RTP Session port
     */
    int port = 49200;
    /**en
     * Media Type i.e. one of audio or video
     */
    String media = "video";

    /////////////DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE//////////////////////////

    // our main rtpsocket abstraction to which we will create and send
    // to the Manager for appropriate handler creation
    RTPSocket rtpsocket = null;
    // the control RTPIODataSource of the RTPSocket above
    RTPPushDataSource rtcpsource = null;
    // The GUI to handle our player
    PlayerWindow playerWindow;
    // The handler created for our RTP session, as returned by the Manager
    Player player = null;
    // maximum size of buffer for UDP receive from the sockets
    private  int maxsize = 2000;

    UDPHandler  rtp = null;
    UDPHandler rtcp = null;

    public VideoChatRTP(String address, int port){

        this.address = address;
        this.port = port;
        try {
            // create the RTPSocket
            rtpsocket = new RTPSocket();
            // set its content type : rtpraw/video for a video session and
            // rtpraw/audio for an audio session
            String content = "rtpraw/" + media;
            rtpsocket.setContentType(content);
            // set the RTP Session address and port of the RTP data
            rtp = new UDPHandler(address, port);
            // set the above UDP Handler to be the sourcestream of the rtpsocket
            rtpsocket.setOutputStream(rtp);
            // set the RTP Session address and port of the RTCP data
            rtcp = new UDPHandler(address, port +1);
            // get a handle over the RTCP Datasource so that we can set
            // the sourcestream and deststream of this source to the rtcp
            // udp handler we created above.
            rtcpsource = rtpsocket.getControlChannel();
            // Since we intend to send RTCP packets from the network to
            // RTPSM and vice-versa, we need to set the RTCP UDP handler
            // as both the input and output stream of the rtcpsource.
            rtcpsource.setOutputStream(rtcp);
            rtcpsource.setInputStream(rtcp);
            // set the dynamic info on the RTPSocket, so that we can
            // playback DVI as well
            if (media.equals("audio"))
                EncodingUtil.Init(rtpsocket);
            // start & connect the RTP socket data source before creating
            // the player
            try{
                rtpsocket.connect();
                player = Manager.createPlayer(rtpsocket);
                //rtpsocket.start();
            } catch (NoPlayerException e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                //      e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                //      e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            if (player != null){
                player.addControllerListener(this);
                // send this player to out playerwindow
                playerWindow = new PlayerWindow(player);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("could not connect to RTP stream."); }

    }

    public synchronized void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent ce) {

        if ((ce instanceof DeallocateEvent) ||
        (ce instanceof ControllerErrorEvent)){
            // stop udp handlers
            if (rtp != null)
                rtp.close();
            if (rtcp != null)
                rtcp.close();
        }

    }

    // method used by inner class UDPHandler to open a datagram or
    // multicast socket as the case maybe
    private DatagramSocket InitSocket(String sockaddress, int sockport){

        InetAddress addr = null;
        DatagramSocket sock = null;
        try{
            addr = InetAddress.getByName(sockaddress);
            if (addr.isMulticastAddress()){
                MulticastSocket msock = new MulticastSocket(sockport);
                msock.joinGroup(addr);
                sock = (DatagramSocket)msock;
            }else{
                sock = new
                DatagramSocket(sockport,addr);
            }
            return sock;
        }
        catch (SocketException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }// end of InitSocket

    //INNER CLASS UDPHandler which will receive UDP RTP Packets and
    //stream them to the handler of the sources stream. IN case of
    //RTCP , it will also accept RTCP packets and send them on the
    //underlying network.
    public class UDPHandler extends Thread implements PushSourceStream, OutputDataStream{

        DatagramSocket mysock = null;
        DatagramPacket dp = null;
        SourceTransferHandler outputhandler = null;
        String myaddress = null;
        int myport;
        boolean closed = false;

        // in the constructor we open the socket and create the main
        // UDPHandler thread.
        public UDPHandler(String haddress, int hport){

            myaddress = haddress;
            myport = hport;
            mysock = InitSocket(myaddress,myport);
            setDaemon(true);
            start();

        }

        // the main thread simply receives RTP data packets from the
        // network and transfer's this data to the output handler of
        // this stream.
        public void run(){
            int len;
            while(true){
                if (closed){
                    cleanup();
                    return;
                }
                try{
                    do{
                        dp = new DatagramPacket(new byte[maxsize],maxsize);
                        mysock.receive(dp);
                        if (closed){
                            cleanup();
                            return;
                        }
                        len = dp.getLength();
                        if (len > (maxsize >> 1))
                            maxsize = len << 1;
                    }
                    while (len >= dp.getData().length);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    cleanup();
                    return;
                }

                if (outputhandler != null)
                    outputhandler.transferData(this);
            }
        }

        public void close(){
            closed = true;
        }

        private void cleanup(){
            mysock.close();
            stop();
        }

        // methods of PushSourceStream
        public Object[] getControls() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        public Object getControl(String controlName) {
            return null;
        }

        public  ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor(){
            return null;
        }

        public long getContentLength(){
            return SourceStream.LENGTH_UNKNOWN;
        }

        public boolean endOfStream(){
            return false;
        }

        // method by which data is transferred from the underlying
        // network to the RTPSM.
        public int read(byte buffer[], int offset, int length) {

            System.arraycopy(dp.getData(),
            0,
            buffer,
            offset,
            dp.getLength());
            return dp.getData().length;

        }

        public int getMinimumTransferSize(){
            return dp.getLength();
        }

        public void setTransferHandler(SourceTransferHandler transferHandler){
            this.outputhandler = transferHandler;
        }

        // methods of PushDestStream used by teh RTPSM to transfer
        // data to the underlying network.
        public int write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) {

            InetAddress addr = null;
            try{
                addr = InetAddress.getByName(myaddress);
            }catch (UnknownHostException e){
            }
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer,length,addr,myport);
            try{
                mysock.send(dp);
            }catch (IOException e){}
            return dp.getLength();

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new VideoChatRTP("239.1.2.3", 1234);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }



    }


}
```

EncodingUtilClass.java

```
import javax.media.rtp.RTPPushDataSource;
import javax.media.rtp.RTPControl;
import javax.media.rtp.RTPSocket;
import javax.media.rtp.SessionManager;
import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;
public class EncodingUtil {
private static final String rtpcontrol = "javax.media.rtp.RTPControl";

public static void Init(RTPPushDataSource ds){

    RTPControl control = (RTPControl)ds.getControl(rtpcontrol);
    if (control == null){
        //System.out.println("The datasource " + ds +
        //         "\n does not support the RTPControl interface..." +
        //         "\nexiting from EncodingUtil.Init()");
        return;
    }
    Init(control);
}

    public static void Init(SessionManager mgr){

         Format format = null;

        if (mgr == null)
            return;

        format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.DVI, 44100, 8, 1);
        mgr.addFormat(format, 18);

    }

    public static  void Init(RTPControl control){

        Format format = null;
        if (control == null)
            return;

        format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.DVI, 44100, 8, 1);
        control.addFormat(format, 18);

    }

}
```

When I run the program, it catches the `NoPlayerException` and prints `Cannot find a Player for: javax.media.rtp.RTPSocket@1eb0`.
Whole error message if printStackTrace:

```
Cannot find a Player for: javax.media.rtp.RTPSocket@1dee400
javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for: javax.media.rtp.RTPSocket@1dee400
    at javax.media.Manager.createPlayerForSource(Manager.java:1512)
    at javax.media.Manager.createPlayer(Manager.java:500)
    at VideoChatRTP.<init>(VideoChatRTP.java:80)
    at VideoChatRTP.main(VideoChatRTP.java:280)
```

I have taken into consideration the JAR files and put the `jmf.properties` in the same folder where the JAR files are. Please help me fix this. I'm still learning Java. Thank you in advance.